# Self referencing in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

how can i get the type of of an object (with `GetType`) from within the object itself?

Something like `GetType(Me)` (that, of course, doesn't work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Me.GetType()` should work. If it doesn't, then please say in what way it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of `typeof(Me)` ?